# PDF Shell Extension Handler

Tags: windows-7, shell, pdf, shell-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I view and sort after the page count for multiple PDF files in a Windows file explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/493409/how-can-i-view-and-sort-after-the-page-count-for-multiple-pdf-files-in-a-windows)

Is there any Shell Extension Handler for Windows 7 **64b**, that can show PDF meta-data (e.g. pages) in Windows explorer?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather on Google, Adobe Reader installs a preview handler for the shell as part of its normal installation. There's a picture of it [here](http://www.pretentiousname.com/adobe_pdf_x64_fix/).